# Lazy match in unix bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am new to shell scripting and unix commands and am trying to find a good way to do a lazy match between patterns in a file and haven't been able to get the output I want to see. The text looks like the following example (Edit: Revised text string

```
"hello
how
are
you
right
now
and
hey how
you
doing
thanks
see
you
and
ask
me if I
am
doing
okay"
```

Desired output:

```
hey how
you
doing
```

I have tried to use multiple answers I found here for similar issues involving sed, grep or awk and I keep seeing this output instead:

```
how
are
you
right
now
and
hey how
you
doing
thanks
see
you
and
ask
me if I
am
doing
```

I just want to perform a lazy match between the word "how" and "doing" and print the lines in between (inclusive) (and preferably how to use the solution to assign the returned text to a variable in a shell script)

Thanks in advance

Edit

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to use the term lazy matching. At least coming from someone familiar with regex, your actual result matches what `how.*?doing` would yield.

Comment: try using awk 
    
    awk '/hey/,/doing/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to perform a lazy match between the word "how" and "doing" and print the lines in between

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'p{s = s ORS $0} /how$/{p=1; s=$0} p && /doing$/{print s; p=0}' file
```

```
hey how
you
doing
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have a couple more questions if that's okay. What if my original text looks like this instead: 

`code` "hello
how
are
you
right
now
and
hey how
you
doing
thanks
see
you
and
ask
me if I
am
doing
okay" `code`

and I want to see the same desired output from my OP

Comment: You cannot provide data in comments as it looses formatting. Better you edit your question and add this sample data with expected output.

Comment: Just edited my question with the new source text. Thanks again

Comment: Even for your updated output this command will produce sane output.

Comment: Thanks, you're right... Your solution works for the new text string too